# How do i get hover:scale-125 to work in tailwindCSS?

Tags: hover, tailwind-css

As a noob in tailwind, im stuck.
I want my image to scale a tiny bit when hovering over the box.

(When i enter my code in tailwind play, it works perfectly)
https://play.tailwindcss.com/nLuHp6nW7E

But in my visual studio code, im doing exactly the same butthe image stays static when hovering.

My code:

```
<div class="container mx-auto py-8">
    <h1 class="text-2xl text-center font-extrabold mb-4">Browse through our selection</h1>
    
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <!-- Box 1 -->
        <div class="w-60 max-w-xs flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-gray-200 bg-opacity-50 border-2  rounded-lg p-10 transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-gray-300 box-sizing:border-box mr-8 mb-8 border-yellow-600">
            <img src="smoke.png" alt="Flashbangs" class="block h-16 hover:scale-125">
            <span class="text-sm mt-2 font-bold">Smokes</span>
        </div>
```

I hope someone has some suggestions/tips :)

Looked for Conflicting Rules, but could not find any.
Checked everytransition, scale, and hover properties to see if they conflict.

Comment: Consider checking the file the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}



My html + styles.css are in a public folder. 
Tailwind style components (@tailwind base; etc ) are in my src folder.

This should be correct right?